# Consulta sobre Base de Datos - Sacar dos datos que más se repiten por cada inicial de un nombre

Tags: mysql

tengo un problemilla con una base de datos, a ver si me podéis echar un cable.

Tengo una base de datos de trabajadores, que tienen nombre, id... Estos trabajadores se repiten a lo largo de la tabla.

Lo que necesito es que por cada inicial me saque los dos nombres que más se repiten, es decir:

- (A) Antonio se repite 1 vez, Álvaro 7 y Alberto 5
- (B) Berto 3, Billy 6 y Borja 8

Y así sucesivamente

Lo que tengo es:

```
SELECT Nombre as Nombre, COUNT(*) AS VecesRepetido
FROM lista
GROUP BY Nombre
HAVING COUNT(Nombre) >1;
```

Con esto me saca todos los nombres que se repiten en la lista, ordenados alfabéticamente. Pero me saca TODOS los que se repiten, que pueden ser 6 nombres que empiecen por la A, y no los dos que más lo hacen.

Entonces el programa me debería sacar

```
Álvaro 7, Alberto 5, Billy 6, Borja 8.
```

Gracias, un saludo!

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado hasta ahora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo así podría servirte. Utiliza `SUBSTR` para recoger la primera letra de cada nombre. Y después haces otra `select` para hacer que sólo muestre 2.

```
SELECT Nombre, Inicial,
FROM(
SELECT Nombre as Nombre, SUBSTR(Nombre,1,1) as Inicial, COUNT(*) AS VecesRepetido 
FROM lista 
GROUP BY Nombre, Inicial HAVING COUNT(Nombre) >1;
)
WHERE COUNT(Inicial) < 3;
```